# Proving that CDFs of maximum and $\frac{1}{k}$ sum are equal for $X_i \sim \text{Exp}(1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ i.i.d random variables such that $X_i \sim \text{Exp}(1)$.

Prove that CDF of $\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k$ is identical to CDF of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} X_k$, i.e $$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_1 + \dotsc + \frac{X_{n}}{n} \leq t\Big) = \mathbb{P}\big(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k \leq t\big).$$

I've showed that $\mathbb{P}\big(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k \leq t\big) = (1-e^{-t})^n$ proved the identity for $n = 2$. Then tried to show it by induction, but struggled with the final integral

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(X_1 + \dotsc + \frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} \leq t\bigg)  &= \int_{x_{n+1}} \mathbb{P}\bigg(X_1 + \dotsc + \frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} \leq t, X_{n+1} = (n+1)x_{n+1}\bigg) \ \text{d}x_{n+1} \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{t} \mathbb{P}\bigg(X_1 + \dotsc + \frac{X_{n}}{n} \leq t - x_{n+1} \bigg) e^{-(n+1)x_{n+1}} \ \text{d}x_{n+1} \\
&= \int_{0}^{t} \Big(1-e^{x_{n+1}- t}\Big)^n e^{-(n+1)x_{n+1}}  \ \text{d}x_{n+1} 
\end{align*}$$

I feel I did something wrong with marginalisation of $X_{n+1}$. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) if $X\sim Exp(1)$ it is very easy to verify that $\frac{X}{k}\sim Exp(k)$

2) the density of the $max(X_i)$ is the following

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
f_{max}(z)=n e^{-z}(1-e^{-z})^{n-1} 
\qquad  (1)
}
$$

Now it is very easy to check the density of the various sum with the convolution

n=2

$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^z e^{-x}2e^{-2(z-x)}dx=2e^{-z}(1-e^{-z})$$

n=3

$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^z 2e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})3e^{-3(z-x)}dx=3e^{-z}(1-e^{-z})^2$$

and so on...

this prove what requested: as you can see the densities are equivalent to the general formula (1)

Comment: Thank you! :) I didn't think to consider the convolution